# Grab entire document tree with OpenOffice API

Tags: java, c++, openoffice.org

I would like to grab the entire tree for a [Writer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Writer) document in [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) 3.1. I need to collect data on all the elements in the tree, not only the `Text` elements.

By loading the `XTextDocument` and doing `getText()` will give the `XText` element. More specifically, using an `XEnumerationAccess` from the `XText` will only iterate over the `TextRange`.

From the OpenOffice documentation [/DevGuide/Text/Iterating_over_Text](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Iterating_over_Text):

> The second interface of com.sun.star.text.Text is XEnumerationAccess. A Text service enumerates all *paragraphs* in a text and returns objects which support com.sun.star.text.Paragraph. This includes tables, because writer sees tables as specialized paragraphs that support the com.sun.star.text.TextTable service.

Some additional documentation here:

> The text portion enumeration of a paragraph *does not* supply contents which do belong to the paragraph, but do not fuse together with the text flow. These could be text frames, graphic objects, embedded objects or drawing shapes anchored at the paragraph, characters or as character. The TextPortionType "TextContent" indicate if there is a content anchored at a character or as a character. If you have a TextContent portion type, you know that there are shape objects anchored at a character or as a character.

My test documents indicate that I do get a [XTextContent](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextContent.html) and the [XTextRange](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextRange.html) can be collected via `getAnchor()`. But how can I determine the type of content that I am collecting? The only method is `getString()`. If the object was an embedded image, how do I collect its data?

I am using C++ but I believe a solution in Java would be portable.

---

**Migrated From Answer**

Due to poor formatting, this comment is posted as an answer.

Thanks for your response.

I intend to use the API.

I am trying the example of collecting `GrahicObjects` from the document. By using a `XGraphicObjectsSupplier` I can get a collection via `getGraphicObjects()`. The object from the collection is `Any` and printing the type via `getValueTypeName()` gives `XTextContent`.

The API describes that the collection holds a `TextGraphicObject` "service". How do I grab an instance of it?

Answer (score 0):

Answers for your question would be complicated but I'll try to make myself understandable.

- Exporting the document to XML would
  be easier to process using SAX. If
  using the XML way, you would have to
  implement *XDocumentHandler* and read
  the document(optionally filter what
  you don't need). The rest of the work would be either XSLT transformations or SAX for big documents.
- If you prefer using only the API,
  you'll have to play a lot with
  *XServiceInfo* and *UnoRuntime.queryInterface*

Answer (score 0):

in java:

```
XComponentContext xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap();
XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();
Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);
XDesktop xDesktop = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDesktop.class, oDesktop);
XComponentLoader xCompLoader = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class, xDesktop);
XComponent xComp = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL("file:///C:/test.odt", "_blank", 0, new Boolean(true));
XTextDocument xDoc = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, xComp);
XModel xModel =UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XModel.class, xDoc );
XDrawPageSupplier xDPS = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDrawPageSupplier.class, xModel);
XDrawPage xDrawPage = xDPS.getDrawPage();
XShapes xShapes = UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XShapes.class, xDrawPage );
for (int s=0;s<xDrawPage.getCount();s++) {
   XShape xShape = UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XShape.class, xShapes.getByIndex(s) );
   System.out.println(" -- sh.getShapeType: " + xShape.getShapeType());
   System.out.println(" -- sh.getPosition: " + xShape.getPosition().X + "x" + xShape.getPosition().Y);
   System.out.println(" -- sh.getSize: " + xShape.getSize().Width + "x" + xShape.getSize().Height);
}
```